# Is "thankyou" acceptable as a single word?

Tags: orthography

I was doing a small piece of language translation in Google Translate, and it detected the use of "thankyou" in the text and asked "do you mean - thank you".

Is the single word version - thankyou - an aberration?

Comment: It's not even non-standard. It's a mistake/not acceptable.

Comment: The Macquarie Pocket Dictionary has 'thankyou' listed. I was surprised but still don't think I'll be using it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

*Thank you* is a sentence. If you want to use one word, *thanks* is acceptable. However, *thankyou* is not acceptable as a single word.

Comment: it's inconsistent though: goodbye is one word while thankyou is not.

Comment: @Rob _Goodbye_ should be four words, but obviously that wouldn’t work so well. Unlike _thank you_, which is still quite transparently two separate words, “(I) thank” [a verb] and “you” [the object of the verb], _goodbye_ is by now an unanalysable unit that cannot be split up, unless you prefer to write it ‘etymologically’ as _go(o)d b [ ] ye_. I would seriously advise against doing that.

Answer (score 6):

No, **thankyou** is not an aberration. It just has a different definition.

- **thank you** (verb *to thank*, direct object *you*) — this is how you say thank you. Essentially short for "I thank you".
- **thank-you** or **thankyou** (noun) — an act of thanking. As in: "He gave a big thankyou for..."; "There were thank-yous all around".
- **thank-you** or **thankyou** (modifier before a noun) — as in "a thankyou card".

For the noun and modifier forms, most dictionaries seem to prefer the hyphenated **thank-you**, but also list **thankyou** as a valid alternative form.

Sources: [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thank-you), [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/thankyou).

But [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thankyou) only lists the hyphenated form, not the single-word form.

Comment: Only wiktionary gives 'thankyou' as a possibility; that only reduces my trust in wiktionary rather than increase my acceptance of ..the non-hyphenated version of 'thank-you'.

Comment: The Dictionary.com link is to its page for "thankyou". Also I have personally seen it written "thankyou" many times. Going from hyphenated to single-word is a valid path that many compound words have taken. I don't know when a common misspelling crosses the line to become a valid alternative form?

Comment: That particular page at dictionary.com looks like it was created by an automatic process. Anyway, it could be adopted eventually, but in my (fairly loose) standard, it really looks like a mistake. It's hard...is 'wierd' acceptable? I think not, but I could be...mistaken.

Comment: The Collins and Macmillan online dictionaries both have an entry for the single word.

Comment: @tunny this question was posted three years ago, so perhaps dictionaries have updated their entries. If callum and others are right, this means the answers which have gained the most upvotes are mistaken.

Answer (score 5):

*Thankyou* is not a word; hence unacceptable.  Also it looks illiterate, because literate people know how to spell "thank you".

Comment: Still, highly literate Anglophones do make this mistake *a lot*!

Answer (score 1):

Languages evolve. There's no reason thankyou can't be a single word just like goodbye. Once enough people use it that way long enough, it will be added to the dictionaries as a legitimate form of a real word. I personally am doing my part to hasten this particular bit of English language evolution because I like the form better. Thankyou for listening!

Comment: I daresay you could find better examples than _goodbye_ as parallels, since (as I just noted in my comment to simchona’s answer) there is actually a reason why _goodbye_ and _thank you_ should not really go down the same road—at least not just yet. Thus far, I’ll just thankgod for the fact that _thankyou_ has not yet become accepted, ’cause I sure as hell don’t like it. **Especially** as a phrase.